# How to fetch data using Left Join when using Beedo Raw SQL to query?

Tags: go, beego

I am getting an error with the below code, it is not fetching any row:

```
type User struct {

    Id       int
    Username string
    Name     string
    Age      int
}

type Salory struct {

    Id        int
    Username  string 
    Salory    string
    Reamrk    string
}

var detail []*models.Salory 

if num, err := orm.NewOrm().Raw("SELECT salory.id, salory.salory, salory.reamrk, salory.username, user.username, user.name FROM salory LEFT JOIN user ON salory.username = user.username ORDER BY id ASC",).QueryRows(&detail); 
err == nil {
      fmt.Printf("%d Total rows read\n", num)

        for _, post := range detail {

            fmt.Printf("Id: %d, UserName: %d, Name: %s\n", post.Id, post.Salory.Username, post.Remark)
            }


    }
```

I want to know the concept of Left Join in Beego Using Raw SQL to query

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: If this is a direct copy & paste of your code, you have a typo. You are referring to a table as both `salory` and `sallory`. There may be other issues too, but that one jumped out at me.

Comment: no this is not the problem

U know Golang beego framework ?

Comment: Use gofmt. You have some very poorly formatted Go code.  (extra commas, semicolons, bad indentation, etc).

Comment: To address your question: The concept of a left join is foreign to Beego. Left joins (and any other SQL) are only relevant to the SQL server you're using. Beego just consumes the data that's passed to it. Get your query working, and Beego will follow suit.